# Where is S60 5th Ed SDK Context Sensitive GUI

Tags: symbian

In 5th Ed SDK it says:
Launch the CS Help compiler GUI from the start menu option: start->programs->Symbian xx SDKs->Development Tools->CSHelp Compiler where Symbian xx SDKs is the version of the SDK you have installed.

But I can't find it :(

Has it been removed from the SDK ? Is there any sufficient tool to get the job done ?

My operating system is Windows7 pro.

Best Regards.

Comment: I hope I can find some help as I've been looking for days in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it from console:
cshlpcmp yourapp.cshlp